# Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined in express website

Tags: express, discord.js

web.js:

```
   let login = req.cookies["login"] ? req.cookies["login"] : null;
   var guilds = await oauth.getUserGuilds(login).catch(() => null);
   let guildx = guilds.find(i => i.id === req.params.guildID);
   let guild = (await client.shard.fetchClientValues('guilds.cache')).flat().filter(i => i.id === guildx.id)[0];
```

manage.ejs (guild page for manage):

```
<% guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel=> {
   if(channel.type !== "text" && channel.type !== "news") return;
   channel.name = channel.name.replace("-", " ")
   let marks;
   if(channel.type === "text") marks = "#️⃣"
   if(channel.type === "news") marks = ""
 %> html code <% }) %>
```

error:
Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Please help me :D

I don't know how to fix it so I am asking you for help :/
I tried in many ways, but it still does not work, if someone has any ideas, please write a reply

Comment: add `console.log(guild.channels);` before `guild.channels.cache.forEach(...`. What is the value of `cache` attribute?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky
`[
  '835643596392759297',
  '835643596392759298',
  '835643596392759299',
  '835643596392759300'
]`

Comment: So `cache` is an array of __strings__. But `channel=> {
   if(channel.type !== "text" && channel.type !== "news")..` means every item of the array is an __object__ with a `type` attribute